# React Axios Delete Not rendering every time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-hooks, json-server

I have three files worth of code posted below. For some reason, when I use my delete button, the React app will re-render but only sometimes. I am using axios and tried changing the onClick={deletionHandler} to onClick={() => deletionHandler} and a few other methods. My question is, what is wrong with my handleDeletion function? Why does it only re-render sometimes, even though I set the Persons state variable, which should re-render the page, right? I see in my json-server db.json file that the deletion is successful, it's just that the re-rendering isn't working. When it doesn't work and I click the delete button again for a database item that has been deleted, I get the follow result:

DELETE http://localhost:3001/persons/1 404 (Not Found)

Thanks

```js
import Persons from './components/Persons'
import Filter from './components/Filter'

const App = ({jsonPersons}) => {
  const [persons, setPersons] = useState(jsonPersons)
  const [ newName, setNewName ] = useState('')
  const [ newNumber, setNewNumber ] = useState('')
  const [ filter, setFilter ] = useState('')

  **function handleDeletion(event){
    const idToDelete = event.target.value
    handlePerson
    .deletion(idToDelete)
    handlePerson
    .getAll().then(persons => {
      setPersons(persons)
    })
  }**

  function handleClick(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    if(persons.some(person =>  person.name === newName)){
      alert(`${newName} i ..s already added to phonebook`)
      setNewName('')
      return
    }
    const personObject = {
      name:newName,
      number:newNumber
    }
    handlePerson
    .create(personObject)
    .then(returnedPerson => {
      setPersons(persons.concat(returnedPerson))
      setNewName('')
      setNewNumber('')
    })

  }
  const handleNameChange = (event) => {
    setNewName(event.target.value)
  }
  const handleNumberChange = (event)=> {
    setNewNumber(event.target.value)
  }
  const handleFilterChange = (event) => {
    setFilter(event.target.value)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Phonebook</h2>
      <Filter filter={filter} onChange={handleFilterChange}/>
      <h2>add a new</h2>
      <PersonForm
      name={newName}
      number={newNumber}
      handleName={handleNameChange}
      handleNumber={handleNumberChange}
      handleClick={handleClick}
      />
      <h2>Numbers</h2>
      <Persons
      persons={persons}
      filter={filter}
      deletionHandler={handleDeletion}/>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

```js
const Persons = ({persons,filter,deletionHandler}) => {
  const personsToShow = filter
  ? persons.filter(person => person.name.toLowerCase().includes(filter.toLowerCase()))
  : persons

  return(personsToShow.map(person => {
    return <p key={person.id}> {person.name} {person.number} <button value={person.id} onClick={deletionHandler}> delete </button></p>}
  ))
}
export default Persons
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

```js
{
  "persons": [
    {
      "name": "Jsadwad",
      "number": "wdawd",
      "id": 12
    },
    {
      "name": "wadwd",
      "number": "dawda",
      "id": 13
    }
  ]
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `useEffect`.

Try this :

```
...

const App = ({ jsonPersons }) => {
  const [ persons, setPersons ] = useState([])   <---- empty array
  const [ newName, setNewName ] = useState('')
  const [ newNumber, setNewNumber ] = useState('')
  const [ filter, setFilter ] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {                              <---- useEffect
   setPersons(jsonPersons)
  }, [jsonPersons])

  function handleDeletion(event){
    const idToDelete = event.target.value
    handlePerson
    .deletion(idToDelete)
    handlePerson
    .getAll().then(persons => {
      setPersons(persons)
    })
  }

...
```

When `jsonPersons` changes a render is started and the state `persons` also changes